# iOS7 Fullscreen uiview.. why disappear status bar?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview, ios7

(i can't speak english well T.T)

I want fullscreen uiview in uiviewcontroller.

I use this code.

```
  - (IBAction)addBtn:(id)sender {

    addView = [[AddView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

    [[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate].window addSubview:addView];
    addView.window.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar;

    [addView setAlpha:0.0f];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.35f];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

    [addView setAlpha:1.0f];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

when click button (+)

disappear status bar!!!!!!!

when i use same code in ios6, it's worked.
but in ios7 not worked.

why disappear status bar?

[check my sorce code here.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/16qrgur1dnqioug/PleaseHelpMe.zip)

Comment: Without having seen your views: maybe the statusbar is just not visible because its text color is the same as the underlying view's background color. in this case you can checkout http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/09/developers-guide-to-the-ios-7-status-bar/ to change the status bar's text color.

Comment: Chris thanks your comment. but i use [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent]; and "View controller-based status bar appearance - NO". I do not think it is a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write below code in viewdidLoad function...

your code......///

```
[addView setAlpha:0.5];// make addsubview alpha 0.5
```

Hope it will work...my friend!!!!

Happy Coding!!!!!!

Comment: thanks your answer. but i want covered status bar. like alertview.

Comment: thanks NiravPatel. my english is very poor... i want uiview overlap statusbar like alerview black background.

Comment: very very thanks your comment!! NiravPatel. please check this image. https://www.dropbox.com/s/ycarzi11lrdgmm2/Untitled-1.png

Comment: ok , so do you want second image...? you want to cover your status bar with addView?

Comment: what you can do is make your addview frame hegiht to full size (568 for iphone5 and 480 for iphone4) , then try to add it in window) like this.. addView = [[AddView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,568)];

Comment: Thanks for your solution NiravPatel. I try that, but still disappear status bar.... T_T

Comment: ok...now don't make alpha 0.0  , make it  [addView setAlpha:0.5];. make addsubview alpha 0.5

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove this line, `addView.window.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar;`

```
- (IBAction)addBtn:(id)sender {

        addView = [[AddView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

        [[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate].window addSubview:addView];
            // addView.window.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar;

        [addView setAlpha:0.0f];

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.35f];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

        [addView setAlpha:1.0f];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
```

Comment: thanks your answer. but i want covered status bar. like alertview.

Comment: why you use addView.window.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar;? this line only getting disappear statusbar.

Comment: thanks for your comment. i want my addView like alertview. UIWindowLevelStatusBar is worked ios6. check this image. https://www.dropbox.com/s/ycarzi11lrdgmm2/Untitled-1.png

Answer (score 0):

Hi here is the code for your addBtn Method.

```
-(IBAction)addBtn:(id)sender {

    addView = [[AddView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

    [[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate].window addSubview:addView];
    addView.window.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelNormal;

    [addView setAlpha:0.0f];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.35f];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

    [addView setAlpha:1.0f];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

It is working fine now.

Comment: thanks your answer. but i want covered status bar. like alertview.